# wide text leads to bad UI

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Did you just now push a UI change?  Wide text in a query pushes the entire body to overlap (underneath) the righthand nav column.

Example:  [MySQL query very slow with multiple concurrent users in a short time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/254700/mysql-query-very-slow-with-multiple-concurrent-users-in-a-short-time)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339651 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391884 marked as fixed